# Making a scrolling Text in the title bar in c# in a visual studio form

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio

I need to create a scrolling text(marquee) in the title bar of a visual studio 2019 windows.net framework form. I've tried many different ideas but cant seem to get it to work. I know someone mentioned they did it with like 2 lines of code and one variable and the length property but I can't figure it out. Any Ideas?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it:

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WinFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private string _text;
        private Timer _textTimer;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Closed += Form1_Closed;
        }

        private void _textTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Text == string.Empty)
            {
                Text = _text;
            }

            Text = Text.Substring(1);
        }

        private void Form1_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _textTimer.Dispose();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _text = Text;
            _textTimer = new Timer();
            _textTimer.Interval = 100;
            _textTimer.Tick += _textTimer_Tick;
            _textTimer.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

But unlike WinAmp, this happens on **both** the form and the taskbar.

A good behavior would be to do that [only on the taskbar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/drawing-a-minimized-window?redirectedfrom=MSDN) as it quickly becomes annoying to see it in the form itself.